# Ctrl-C not terminating Rails Server when using Jruby and Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, pry

I've put a `binding.pry` statement in one of my ruby files to do some debugging and the pry console shows up as expected. However, I am now unable to exit the Rails server using ctrl-c. I get this error

```
ERROR Interrupt: Interrupt
    /home/usrname/.gem/jruby/1.9/gems/pry-0.10.3-java/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:98:in `load_traps'
```

Using jruby 1.7.25 and rails 4 if that matters.

Comment: try ctrl + d instead of ctrl + c

Comment: If using ubuntu,kill the process using ps -aux || grep rails and kill the rails process using kill -9 process_id....

Comment: Firstly you have to exit pry session before you exit the rails server. else find the process and kill it forcefully.

Comment: @Yifei W was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: @Joel, no because it doesn't address 1. Why the trap error occurs. 2. How to exit without the error occurring. I'm well aware I could just `bg` and then `kill %1`

Answer (score 1):

To step out of a loop you can use `!!!`

To exit the server session you can use `exec('kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)')` assuming your rails server is running on port 3000

Answer (score 0):

If you are in debugging mode type

```
exit
```

instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

There is one issue related to exit do refer [this](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/933) which says use

```
exit!
```

Comment: I don't need to exit the debug session. I need to exit the server process.